# Mesh modifications are shown in viewport but not rendered

Tags: rendering, animation, mesh, scripting

Usually I use Processing and Java for my graphics, but I thought it would be nice to try out some Blender scripting because I really like the quality of the cycles render engine.

I am currently working on animations based on the supershape-formula (-> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superformula) in 3D-space.

My work is based on an algorithm that would just generate one mesh based on certain parameters and I adapted it so it could be animated (I would love to give credit for it and I will once it's done, but for now I dont have the time to look it up).

Basically it is still the original algorithm, generating a mesh object called 'supershape' and I added some functionality (handler that is triggered by a frame change) that deletes the old mesh and creates a new mesh based on the new parameters (which are linked to the framecount).

It is not the most perfect way to do it, but until now it seemed to work - At least when I change the frame in the timeline.
But when I start rendering an animation it just uses the mesh that was there when I clicked 'render' for every frame.

I guess it might be an issue with the scene or the mesh object not being updated. Is the geometry somehow baked before rendering?
I had a look at the API documentation but couldn't find anything I haven't tried yet. A short link to a command or function would be enough =)

This is the code, I think the problem is somewhere in the low third, but I don't know:

```
import bpy
import math


Unum = 20
Vnum = 20

Uinc = math.pi / (Unum/2)
Vinc = (math.pi/2)/(Vnum/2)

a = -0.06
b = 2.78
n1 = 0.5
n2 = -.48
n3 = 1.3

scale = 3

# calculating the coordinates for the vertices
# ######################################################
def calc_pos(theta,phi,m):
    r1 = 1/(((abs(math.cos(m*theta/4)/a))**n2+(abs(math.sin(m*theta/4)/b))**n3)**n1)
    r2 = 1/(((abs(math.cos(m*phi/4)/a))**n2+(abs(math.sin(m*phi/4)/b))**n3)**n1)
    y = scale * (r1 * math.cos(theta) * r2 * math.cos(phi))
    z = scale * (r1 * math.sin(theta) * r2 * math.cos(phi))
    x = scale * (r2 * math.sin(phi))

    vert = (x,y,z)
    return vert


# generate the mesh based on the framenumber
# ######################################################

def create_supershape(m):

    n = m  *0.005

    # mesh arrays
    verts = []
    faces = []
    edges = []

    #fill verts array
    theta = -math.pi
    for i in range (0, Unum + 1):
        phi = -math.pi/2

        for j in range(0,Vnum + 1):

            verts.append(calc_pos(theta,phi,m))
            phi = phi + Vinc
        theta = theta + Uinc

    #fill faces array
    count = 0
    for i in range (0, (Vnum + 1) *(Unum)):
        if count < Vnum:
            A = i
            B = i+1
            C = (i+(Vnum+1))+1
            D = (i+(Vnum+1))

            face = (A,B,C,D)
            faces.append(face)

            count = count + 1
        else:
            count = 0

    #create mesh and object
    mymesh = bpy.data.meshes.new("supershape")
    myobject = bpy.data.objects.new("supershape",mymesh)

    #set mesh location
    myobject.location = (0,0,0)
    bpy.context.scene.objects.link(myobject)

    #create mesh from python data
    mymesh.from_pydata(verts,edges,faces)
    mymesh.update(calc_edges=True)

    #set the object to edit mode
    bpy.context.scene.objects.active = myobject
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')

    # remove duplicate vertices
    bpy.ops.mesh.remove_doubles() 

    # recalculate normals
    bpy.ops.mesh.normals_make_consistent(inside=False)
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')


    # subdivide modifier
    myobject.modifiers.new("subd", type='SUBSURF')
    myobject.modifiers['subd'].levels = 3

    # ob.data.materials.append(mat)
    mat = bpy.data.materials.get("supershape_mat")
    myobject.data.materials.append(mat)

    # show mesh as smooth
    mypolys = mymesh.polygons
    for p in mypolys:
       p.use_smooth = True

# handler that fires on every frame
# ######################################################

def my_handler(scene): 

    candidate_list = [item.name for item in bpy.data.objects]

    for object_name in candidate_list:
       bpy.data.objects[object_name].select = True

    # remove all selected.
    bpy.ops.object.delete()

    # remove the meshes, they have no users anymore.
    for item in bpy.data.meshes:
        bpy.data.meshes.remove(item)

    frame = scene.frame_current
    create_supershape(frame)

    bpy.context.scene.update()

bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre.append(my_handler)
```